# Can you see your Interpol notice when applying for a visa?

Tags: visas

I understand that you can't really know if you have an interpol notice with you. The red notice database only show a portion of all actual suspects with such notices. In any case, will you know if you have a notice associated to you when you apply for a visa for countries such as USA, Korea, etc.

Comment: According to https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices, you can find out if a Red Notice has been issued by contacting the Commission for the Control of INTERPOL’s Files (CCF).

Comment: @Traveller I presume they'll also ask you for your exact location, and put you on hold for a good long while if you are actually on the list...

Comment: Does the question of seeing notes on yourself have anything to do with a visa? I understand that the *purpose* may be the preparation of a visa request, but would interpol treat that request differently because you want to travel?

Comment: I just want to know if embassies check interpol database to see if their visa applicants have red notices in them. If so, then obviously, these embassies would deny such people of visas. Is this the case?

Comment: @Yap S. It would probably be prudent to assume that they do check. Being on the Interpol list isn’t something that would ever cross the mind of the majority of travellers - according to their web page only around 58,000 names are on it. I’d suppose that if someone did fear they may be listed it would be because they had a good reason to think they were an internationally wanted criminal.